# How to make sure all the subclass threads exited ?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Having -

```
for (int i = 0; i<10 ; i++) {
            Runnable r = new Runnable(){...}
            new Thread(r).start();
        } 
// I want to continue here only after all the subclass threads before exited . 
...
```

How could I make sure all the subclass threads exited before I continue on after the `for` section ?

Does exist any solution besides keep all the `Runnable`'s in a `List<Runnable>` and finally check its `isAlive()` for each element ?

Comment: This is completely the wrong approach. Read up on using `ExecutorSevice` and the Java 5 concurrency API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How could I make sure all the subclass threads exited before I continue on after the for section ?

I'd use the `ExecutorService` classes.  See the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) on them.  Something like:

```
// create a thread pool with 10 workers
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
// or you can create an open-ended thread pool
// ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   threadPool.submit(new Runnable(){...});
}
// once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown
threadPool.shutdown();
```

Then you can wait for them to finish with:

```
threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

If you still want to do your own threads then typically you keep them around in a `List` and call `join()` on each one of them:

```
List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){...});
   thread.start();
   threadList.add(thread);
}
// this waits for all of the threads to finish before continuing
for (Thread thread : threadList) {
   thread.join();
}
```

Comment: This is the correct approach; I would add something on handling errors in execution - with the `ExecutorService` this is much easier due to the `Future` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). It is great for when you want to wait for N threads to be done with something.

Comment: I think that a `CountDownLatch` is the wrong approach here. I think an `ExecutorService` and the `invokeAll` method is a much less error prone way of doing this.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It has its uses, though it would be better if these threads were to continue.